python pass the hashed sha256 phrase to curve25519
There is the following task:
The secret passphrase is hashed SHA256 to retrive the account's private key
The private key is encrypted using Curve25519 to obtain the public key of the account
But when I run the code I get an error:
ValueError: An X25519 private key is 32 bytes long
This is understandable, because sha256 returns a string equal to 64 bits. Please tell me where I'm wrong
Here's the code I'm trying:
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
 
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.x25519 import X25519PrivateKey
from hashlib import sha256

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.hkdf import HKDF
 
#passphrase
passphrase = "asdasfsdfsjddfueirgnuengigtnsenveigvuneirvneriuvniuvnrsbng"
#hashing passphrase sha256
passphrase_sha256 = sha256(passphrase.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
 
#I pass the hash to cruve25519
 private_key = X25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(passphrase_sha256)
 peer_public_key = X25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(passphrase_sha256).public_key()


You must not hex encode the hash (i.e. use digest() instead of hexdigest()). Alternatively, if you absolutely want to hex encode the hash (e.g. for an export), you must perform a hex decoding with bytes.fromhex() when importing with from_private_bytes().

Topaco, Thanks, this worked for me. Could you please advise how I can now convert the resulting public key into hexadecimal?

There are various possibilities, e.g. peer_public_key.public_bytes_raw().hex(). You can find more details in the library documentation, X25519PublicKey.

SHA-256 produces a 64-character hexadecimal string but X25519PrivateKey expects input to be a 32-byte binary string not a hexadecimal string this is why you have to use as recommended from @Topaco bytes.fromhex() or just changing the hexdigest() to digest() (although both approaches works using the digest() is better in term readability and in bigger applications efficiency):
digest:
passphrase_sha256_hex = sha256(passphrase.encode('utf- 
8')).digest()

bytes.fromhex():
passphrase_sha256_hex = sha256(passphrase.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
passphrase_sha256 = bytes.fromhex(passphrase_sha256_hex)
 .....


Isn't that the same as just sha256(...).digest()?

after some more reading.... you are right using the sha256(passphrase.encode('utf-8')). digest() it is even from readability better ... I will be updating my answer thanks for pointing it out
